# How to make a Chakra row clickable without underlining

Tags: javascript, reactjs, href, chakra-ui

I was able to make a row in a table clickable, which is what I want:

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-sinoussi-hxtwj?file=/src/app.js

However, I don't want the first cell to have an underline. I just want it to appear as regular text. How can I achieve this?

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Table,
  Thead,
  Tr,
  Th,
  Td,
  Tbody,
  LinkOverlay,
  LinkBox
} from "@chakra-ui/react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Table variant="simple" size="sm">
      <Thead>
        <Tr>
          <Th>To convert</Th>
          <Th>into</Th>
          <Th isNumeric>multiply by</Th>
        </Tr>
      </Thead>
      <Tbody>
        <LinkBox as={Tr}>
          <LinkOverlay href="https://www.google.com">inches</LinkOverlay>
          <Td>millimetres (mm)</Td>
          <Td isNumeric>25.4</Td>
        </LinkBox>
        <Tr>
          <Td>feet</Td>
          <Td>centimetres (cm)</Td>
          <Td isNumeric>30.48</Td>
        </Tr>
        <Tr>
          <Td>yards</Td>
          <Td>metres (m)</Td>
          <Td isNumeric>0.91444</Td>
        </Tr>
      </Tbody>
    </Table>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to style it using `css`.

Add this to your `app.js`:

```js
import './style.css';
```

Create a file named `style.css` in `src` folder and add the following code:

```css
*{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
}
```

Comment: The text is still purple when iI do that

Comment: Do you know any css? Btw, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the `textDecoration='none'` prop to your link component.

Example:-

```
<LinkBox as={Tr}>
  <LinkOverlay 
    href="https://www.google.com" 
    textDecoration='none'
   >
    inches
   </LinkOverlay>
  <Td>millimetres (mm)</Td>
  <Td isNumeric>25.4</Td>
</LinkBox>
```